# Can i have same number for replication.factor and min.insync.replicas?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to understand the broker config - min.insync.replicas and here is my question.

Question 1 : If i set my replication.factor = 2 and min.insync.replicas =2, how many copies would i have for my message?

Question 2: Can i set replication.factor = 2 and  min.insync.replicas =2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question 1 : If i set my `replication.factor = 2` and `min.insync.replicas = 2`, how many copies would i have for my message?

The copies (replicas) of the data within a topic are dependent on the configuration `replication.factor`. If you set it to 2, you will have 2 copies.

> Question 2: Can i set `replication.factor = 2` and `min.insync.replicas = 2`?

Yes, you can set both values to 2. The `min.insync.replicas` should be less or equal to the replication.factor. However, the `min.insync.replicas` configuration plays a more important role when producing data to the topic. When a producer sets acks to "all" (or "-1"), this configuration specifies the minimum number of replicas that must acknowledge a write for the write to be considered successful. If this minimum cannot be met, then the producer will raise an exception (either `NotEnoughReplicas` or `NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppend`).

The full details of those configuration are given in the section [Topic-Level Configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs) of the Kafka docs.

Comment: thanks for the response mike, As per apache kafka doc, by definition of replication factor, it includes leader. Now my question, does in-sync replicas also include the leader?

Comment: Yes, it is the total number including leader.

Comment: The minimum allowed value for the `min.insync.replicas` is 1, which refers to the leader

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can very well do that. Infact ISR <= RF. Here ISR referes to In-sync replicas and RF refers to the Replication Factor.